# How to customize a workflow details page in Alfresco Share?

Tags: workflow, share, alfresco, activiti

I want to modify the Share workflow details page (`/share/page/workflow-details?workflowId=activiti$XXXXX`). Specifically, I want to replace the column `Type` in the history tables with another one that will show the task title (adding it as a new column is a good solution too). I'm working with Alfresco Community 4.0e.

I read this wiki article [Custom Share Workflow UI](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Custom_Share_Workflow_UI#Workflow_Details_Form) (section "Workflow Details Form"), but that is not the part of the page I need to change.

Any ideas, please?

You can see the columns I want to modify in this picture (see red squares):

[image: Workflow details page screenshot]

For example, where it shows these values (task type):

```
Review

Workflow Task
```

...I want to print this (task name/title):

```
Quality Documents Review

Quality Documents Edition
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- To add new column or modify shown data, you should modify
  `currentTasksColumnDefinitions` and `historyColumnDefinitions` in
  **workflow-form.js** i.e, `apache-tomcat\webapps\share\components\workflow\workflow-form.js`.
- To modify existing task title, you need to modify only in property
  file namely **workflow-messages.properties** in `apache-tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\workflow\workflow-messages.properties`

Comment: Just one detail, though: the page loads a minimized version of the script called workflow-form-min.js, and this is the file you should generate with [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/), taking workflow-form.js as the input file once you are done with the modifications. I used the following command: java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar --
type js --preserve-semi workflow-form.js -o workflow-form-min.js

Comment: The page loads a minimized version workflow-form-min.js or normal version workflow-form.js only depends on you. You can configure it which file will be used in share-config-custom.xml. :D

Comment: swemon, I posted a question on Alfresco Share task forms, I would appreciate your wise insights: [How to add a header to all the user task forms in an Activiti workflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13041662/1701779)